# How to ignore modules in my aggregator POM while executing a plugin

Tags: maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I need to execute a custom plugin on my aggregator POM that should checkout the sub modules. Since the sub-module folder(s) and hence the POM(s) do not exist yet, i always get error like:

```
The project ... has 1 error
[ERROR]     Child module ... of parentproject\pom.xml does not exist
```

Is it possible to ignore the modules while executing a plugin?

**My Mojo Declaration**

```
@Mojo(name = "checkout", aggregator = true)
public class CheckoutMojo extends AbstractMojo {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by introducing a profile within the POM and moved all module names within the profile. Since maven doesn't find any module(s) when it ramps up it ramps up as expected, and then my mojo gets executed. Now the mojo that should run without modules being present is called like:

```
mvn groupId:artifactId:version:goalname
```

And the mojo that should run with modules is called like:

```
mvn groupId:artifactId:version:goalname -Pprofile_having_modules
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `@Mojo` you can add an entry `aggregator = true` so that the plugin is only run on the parent POM, not on the modules.

Comment: i thought it should be aggregator = false. Anyways i tried with true as well. Same error

Comment: Ok, I see. Probably you just cannot run a Maven plugin if the modules mentioned in the POM are not there. The project is just not valid then.

Comment: Please note that letting a plugin check out parts of the project is highly unusual. You should think hard whether it it really necessary to do it. Normally, you put your parent POM and your modules into the same git/svn repository and check out all of it at once.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But its not the case with me here. This POM is not the parent POM. There is another parent POM already.  All modules have their own repository. This POM is supposed to be an an aggregator and should be able to checkout the modules.

Comment: In this case I would check out all the modules _before_ I run any Maven goal.

Comment: Right, I am doing the same for now. I wanted to have a custom checkout goal that does it for me. Seems that is not possible.Thanks.

Comment: Checking out is a job for Jenkins (or whatever build server you use), not for Maven.